# Bluetooth appears to be working but not finding any devices 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 22.04 on GMKtec mini-pc. No wireless or Bluetooth working but Bluetooth shows running but finds no devices and wi-fi won't configure. I read through the other posts but could not find an answer that worked.
Here is all the information about my system. Am I just missing a driver for the Realtek HW?
Please help

```
mwynston@devserver1a:~$ sudo dmesg |grep Bluetooth
[ 1.903844] usb 1-6: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[ 6.146605] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 6.146632] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 6.146641] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 6.146643] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 6.146645] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 6.175248] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
[ 6.383330] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
[ 6.383338] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: unknown IC info, lmp subver 8852, hci rev 000b, hci ver 000b
[ 6.383342] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: assuming no firmware upload needed
[ 7.072802] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 7.072804] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 7.072806] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 20.029157] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 20.029162] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 20.029164] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11



mwynston@devserver1a:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0409 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1058:1230 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Book (WDBFJK)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b85b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:082c Logitech, Inc. HD Webcam C615
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:5409 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0573:1573 Zoran Co. Personal Media Division (Nogatech) USB Audio and HID
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
mwynston@devserver1a:~$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-01-16 11:17:12 EST; 8min ago
Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 1509 (bluetoothd)
Status: "Running"
Tasks: 1 (limit: 38061)
Memory: 2.2M
CPU: 55ms
CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
└─1509 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

mwynston@devserver1a:~$ uname -r
5.15.0-91-generic

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852

Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-6:3
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2

Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I225-V driver: igc v: kernel port: N/A
    bus-ID: 01:00.0
  IF: enp1s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel Ethernet I225-V driver: igc v: kernel port: N/A
    bus-ID: 02:00.0
  IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-3: Realtek driver: N/A port: 3000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
```

Answer (score 0):

See if Secure Boot is enabled with `mokutil --sb` as Secure Boot needs to be disabled for this to work, then

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-5.15.git
sudo dkms add ./bluetooth-5.15
sudo dkms install btusb/4.1
```

Reboot

Comment: Jeremy31 Thank you for the answer. I am not willing to disable secure boot at this time. To much risk in that. If there is no solution without a signed driver or a conf file change I will just pass on getting it working.

Comment: You can try signing the btusb, ath9k, and btrtl with mokutil

Comment: Thank you I will try that. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you it is working now. Jeremy31